# influxdb connect to cloudfront aws

Tags: installation, amazon-cloudfront, influxdb

Just installed influxdb on fedora server 35 with this repo :

```
https://repos.influxdata.com/rhel/8/x86_64/stable/
```

every time i restart the service `influxdb` (default conf) it connects to random ip on aws cloudfront :

```
tcp   ESTAB     0      0            192.168.6.233:44522 143.204.224.81:443   users:(("influxd",pid=45731,fd=16)) timer:(keepalive,20sec,0) uid:988 ino:149215 sk:31 cgroup:/system.slice/influxdb.service <->

tcp   ESTAB     0      0            192.168.6.233:47106   18.64.79.51:443   users:(("influxd",pid=45632,fd=16)) timer:(keepalive,12sec,0) uid:988 ino:148945 sk:29 cgroup:/system.slice/influxdb.service <->
```

I'm pretty new to influxdb and didn't read the manual yet.

Can someone explain this behaviour to me please ?

Thank you

Regards.

Comment: I just needed to read the conf file : /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to read the conf file to get it :

```
/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

disabled the reporting and connection is not established anymore.

```
# Once every 24 hours InfluxDB will report usage data to usage.influxdata.com
# The data includes a random ID, os, arch, version, the number of series and other
# usage data. No data from user databases is ever transmitted.
# Change this option to true to disable reporting.
reporting-disabled = true
```

restarted the service :

```
systemctl restart influxdb
```

checked :

```
ss -lapunte | grep influx
```

only local connections established.

More info here :

https://www.influxdata.com/telemetry/